# Add tag in Pub/Sub message triggered by Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-build

I have a DevOps pipeline as such:

1. Push to a Source Code branch ->
2. Cloud Build trigger builds Docker image ->
3. Upon finish of build, a Cloud Pub/Sub message is pushed to Cloud Functions to deploy the VM.

My question is with the Pub/Sub message sent to Cloud Functions.
I have the Cloud Build with a tag `log-test` but I can't seem to pass it to Cloud Functions.

[image: chicks]

Here is the JSON data from Pub/Sub print out in Functions:

```json
{
    "id": "XXX",
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "source": {
        "repoSource": {
            "projectId": "XXX",
            "repoName": "XXX",
            "commitSha": "XXX"
        }
    },
    "createTime": "2022-06XXXXX",
    "startTime": "2022-XXX:41:11XXX",
    "finishTime": "2022-06-08T07XXX",
    "results": {
        "images": [
            {
                "name": "XXX",
                "digest": "XXX",
                "pushTiming": {
                    "startTime": "2022-06-XXX3733Z",
                    "endTime": "2022-0XXX26.388064947Z"
                }
            }
        ],
        "buildStepImages": [
            "XXX"
        ],
        "buildStepOutputs": [
            ""
        ]
    },
    "steps": [
        {
            "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "-t",
                "XXX",
                "."
            ],
            "timing": {
                "startTime": "2022-06XXX169Z",
                "endTime": "2022-06XXX16549Z"
        ...
        "logging": "XXX",
        "dynamicSubstitutions": XXX,
        "pool": {}
    },
    "logUrl": "https://console.cloud.google.cXXX",
    "substitutions": {
        "TRIGGER_BUILD_CONFIG_PATH": "",
        "REPO_NAME": "XXX",
        "REVISION_ID": "XXX",
        "COMMIT_SHA": "XXX",
        "SHORT_SHA": "XXX",
        "BRANCH_NAME": "master",
        "REF_NAME": "master",
        "TRIGGER_NAME": "logtest"
    },
    "tags": [
        "trigger-XXX"
    ],
    "timing": {
        "FETCHSOURCE": {
            "startTime": "2022-XXX109Z",
            "endTime": "2022-0XXX9740Z"
        },
        "BUILD": {
            "startTime": "2022-0XXXXX042Z",
            "endTime": "2022-06-0XXXXX9576Z"
        },
        "PUSH": {
            "startTime": "202XXXXXX218Z",
            "endTime": "20XXXXX654Z"
        }
    },
    "artifacts": {
        "images": [
            "gcr.io/XXX"
        ]
    },
    "queueTtl": "XXX",
    "name": "projects/XXX/locations/global/builds/XXXX"
}
```

The field of interest to me is the `tag` field found in the JSON:

```json
"tags": [
        "trigger-XXX"
    ],
```

But given the value in the field, this is an auto-generated value which does not contain the expected tag `log-test`.

Is there another field I can pass my tag into?

Answer (score 4):

[Cloud Functions doesn't support the tags](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/tags/tags-supported-services#supported_service_resources) yet. Surprisingly, PubSub neither. The doc should be slightly out of date, or there is a bug.

Anyway, the feature is being deployed broadly. It should come soon to Cloud Functions.

---

You can have a try with Cloud Functions 2ng gen. It's based on Cloud Run, but still in preview. There is chance that the tag works (or not if it's not yet implemented at the preview stage of the development).